# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE read problem

Tags: sql, mysql, load-data-infile

I have a problem using LOAD DATA INFILE commond .

I created a table using the command below;

```
temp.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Patient (patientID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100),address VARCHAR(150), phone VARCHAR(15), birthdate DATE, PRIMARY KEY (patientID))");
```

and trying to read from a file using this command;

```
temp = connect.createStatement();
    temp.executeUpdate("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'patient.txt' INTO TABLE Patient {name,address,phone,birthdate} FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' ");
    temp.executeUpdate(" UPDATE Patient SET name=NULL WHERE name= '-' ");
    temp.executeUpdate( " UPDATE Patient SET address = NULL WHERE address = '-' ");
    temp.executeUpdate(" UPDATE Patient SET phone = NULL WHERE phone = '-' ");
    temp.executeUpdate(" UPDATE Patient SET birthdate = NULL WHERE birthdate = '-'");
```

and my sample text file is this;

```
"omer"  "trabzon"   "3253008"   1990-06-10
"ali"   "ankara"    "2234887"   1999-11-12
```

However it can't read the first fields and skip to the second ones.So,
second fields are replaced to the first fields.

could you help to get the first fields into the right places?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

add a "\N" before "omer" and before "ali" (at the beginning of each row) for the autoincrement column. I would enclose also the date with quotes

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out that problem was the sequence of the load data file line. the right sequence is

```
temp.executeUpdate("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'patient.txt' INTO TABLE Patient FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' {name,address,phone,birthdate}")
```